# WHERE clause combined with - OR LOGICAL Operator in Update a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table table1 with 4 columns and a bunch of rows:

```
| key | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
```

I want to update col_3 with a set of value (value_1) where (col_1 = val or col_2 = val ) , something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET `col_3`= 'value_1' WHERE `col_1` = 'val'  OR   `col_2` = 'val'  ;
```

But it doesn't work, how do I do this?

Erreur :

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.**

Comment: use a key column or set sql_safe_updates to 0 (select @@sql_safe_updates;)

Comment: The error messahe itself is very clear that you are trying to update records without using your key column in where condition. Using non-key columns might update multiple records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable safe update mode using:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```